# heroku db:push not working, using taps gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, taps

I use
  `gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'` on dev and
  `gem 'pg', '0.12.2'` on prod.
  ruby version `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]`

for a tutorial app am developing.

I installed `taps` gem and tried heroku db:push and [this](http://pastie.org/3869446) is what I got.

```
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range: "2012-0
5-06 12:00:00.000000+5894529600"
```

Here is the [heroku log](http://pastie.org/3869462) as well. What is the solution?

FYI: db:pull works very well. I have also checked other similar posts but as of now I couldn't find the solution in any of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a taps bug with Ruby 1.9.3.

The solution, I believe, is to switch to Ruby 1.9.2 *on your local machine* prior to pushing the db files. Like this:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2
heroku db:push
rvm use ruby-1.9.3
```

I do my db:pushes this way and it works for me.

Note that the version of ruby on your heroku app doesn't make a difference. The problem happens when you are running 1.9.3 locally.

Here's a link to the issue in github:

https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/92

Comment: Switching to Ruby 1.9.2 didn't fix the issue for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It didn't fix it for me, either. Did anyone get a solution to this?